# Regex matching characters unless they're at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, replace

Not sure how to explain this, but here it goes.

`$val` could contain a string followed by none, one or multiple dots:

```
test
test.
test..
test... 
etc
```

Using regex I'm looking for any invalid characters in `$val` and then I want to replace them.

```
(preg_replace('-['.$inv.']-',"",$val))
```

`$inv` is an array of invalid entries, this also includes a dot.

How do I strip all `$inv` characters from `$val` EXCEPT any dots on the end?

if `$val = te%st...` the correct result should be test…

if `$val = te.est.` the correct result should be test.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: With "on the end" do you mean word end, line end or text end?

Comment: Can you tell us what your expected output should be?

Comment: if $val = te%st... the correct result should be test...
if $val = te.est. the correct result should be test.
thanks

Comment: @DioF the title suggests it is text end ("end of a string"), I would assume he handles each line (`$val`) separately.

Comment: still struggling with this. any further ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex, simply use `str_replace` to remove all unwanted characters:

```
$replace = array('.', ','); // The characters you want to replace.
echo str_replace($replace, '', '..,.Here,, ..be some text,.');
// Result:
// 'Here be some text'
```

Comment: @user1932360, does this work for you, or not? You can add any character you want to remove, to the `$replace` array.

Comment: This would work, however if I include the . then it would be removed from all the of the string, I need certain dots to remain. 
Please see my updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will remove all non alpha num characters from the string.

```
$string = "Sample text with letters and numbers 45678 and special symbols ($*&#($*#"; 

$new_string = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $string); 

echo $new_string
```

Comment: There are some non alpha characters I want to stay in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<?php
    $val = '
    test
test.
test..
test... 
etc
    ';
    $inv = 'te';
    $ret = preg_replace("@([$inv].+)\.@",'',$val);

    var_dump($val);
    var_dump($ret);
```

$ret now contains

```
test

etc
```